# How to include the original message in a rule-based reply in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-filter

I frequently get some email into Outlook that I'd like to respond to with a set response. I've created a new template message (New Message > (add text) > Save As ... Outlook Template)

Then I created my rule and opted to reply to the message with a specified template. This all works fine.

The problem is that the original message doesn't get sent with the reply, while the subject line is picked up "re: blah, blah, blah", I would like the original message to also be included in the reply.

Can this happen? Am I missing some configuration somewhere, e.g. a variable in the template that will get expanded?

Comment: You can always bounty it.